# Excel version agnostic connection string

Tags: c#, .net, excel, odbc, connection-string

I'm fixing a bug in a .NET project that opens an Excel spreadsheet using ODBC. The app was written in a slightly older version of Excel than the rest of the enterprise has and uses the following connection strings to open Excel files.

```
Xls: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=something;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"

Xlsx: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=something;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
```

I've looked through [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/#p84) and the connection strings reference a specific driver version - so my question is, is there a version agnostic connection string?  I'm concerned that this app is going to break as users upgrade office versions.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Andy. Not that I'm aware of, I use the xlsx example you posted without issue. You can use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver for much older versions of Excel (like ~2003 and before). I've had to do that a few times.